# Compare my VCF to gnomAD variants

Tags: vcf

I have a VCF with small variant calls against HG38 and I would like to determine which of those calls are present in the gnomAD database.

Is there an existing tool that can do this? Should I be looking at variant annotation tools? or is this something that I would look at BCFtools for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [vcfanno](https://github.com/brentp/vcfanno) to annotate your vcf with the gnomad vcf file. There's an example config file for annotating with gnomad (along with other databases such as dbSNP) [here](https://github.com/brentp/vcfanno/blob/master/example/gnomad.conf).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked how fast this is but you could try using [Hail](https://hail.is) (disclaimer: I'm a maintainer). You'll need to install the GCS connector first to read from Google Cloud Storage:

```
curl https://broad.io/install-gcs-connector | python3
```

```py
import hail as hl

mt = hl.import_vcf('your.vcf')
mt = hl.split_multi_hts(mt)  # use the same biallelic representation that gnomAD uses
mt.write('data.mt')  # store in Hail's native format for faster queries
mt = hl.read_matrix_table('data.mt')
sites = hl.read_table(
    'gs://gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/ht/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.ht'
)
mt = mt.anti_join_rows(sites)
```

That'll filter down to just those variants (defined by chromosome, position, and alleles) which are not present in gnomAD v3.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient available disk space, you could download the files from the [gnomad downloads page](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/downloads) and use a [bedtools intersect](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) command to find the overlapping variants.

However, the recommended platforms for gnomAD are to use [hail utilities](https://github.com/broadinstitute/gnomad_methods) developed by them and others, due to the constraints of working with ~1TB of data.

I am not an expert but potentially someone else knows more about using the site hail data.